# Getting channel = null when receiving push notification from urbanairship android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am getting the dreaded 'Developer warning for package "com.mycompany.applicationame" Failed to post notification on channel "null"' Toast message when I send a push notification to my device.  I am running Android API 27.  Here is my code:

```
public class UAAutoPilot extends Autopilot {

@Override
public void onAirshipReady(@NonNull UAirship airship) {
    airship.getPushManager().setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);

    // Android O
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        Context context = UAirship.getApplicationContext();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("customChannel",
                context.getString(R.string.custom_channel),
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    }
    // Create a customized default notification factory
    CustomNotificationFactory notificationFactory;
    notificationFactory = new CustomNotificationFactory(UAirship.getApplicationContext());

    // Set the factory on the PushManager
    airship.getPushManager()
            .setNotificationFactory(notificationFactory);


    airship.getPushManager()
            .getNotificationFactory()
            .setNotificationChannel("customChannel");

}

}
```

Logcat message:

> 2018-11-14 14:00:52.821 1683-13152/system_process
>   E/NotificationService: No Channel found for
>   pkg=com.mycompany.applicationame, channelId=null, id=1007, tag=null,
>   opPkg=com.mycompany.applicationame, callingUid=10081, userId=0,
>   incomingUserId=0, noti

The notification displays, but I am getting this errormessage.  New to UrbanAirship. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't setting the Notification Builder properly.

```
public class CustomNotificationFactory extends NotificationFactory {

Context context;
String channelID = "";

public CustomNotificationFactory(Context context, String channelID) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.channelID = channelID;
}

@Override
public Notification createNotification(PushMessage message, int notificationId) {
    // do not display a notification if there is not an alert
    if (UAStringUtil.isEmpty(message.getAlert())) {
        return null;
    }

    // Build the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(),channelID) //wasn't sending in channelID here.  
            .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(message.getAlert())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);

    // Notification action buttons
    builder.extend(new ActionsNotificationExtender(getContext(), message, notificationId));

    return builder.build();
}

@Override
public int getNextId(PushMessage pushMessage) {
    return NotificationIdGenerator.nextID();
}


@Override
public boolean requiresLongRunningTask(PushMessage message) {
    return false;
}

}
```